# How to find out where ideviceinstaller is installed to?

Tags: macos

I have just installed ideviceinstaller via the command line.

```
Michaels-MacBook-Air:1.0.1 michael.nares$ cd
Michaels-MacBook-Air:~ michael.nares$ brew uninstall ideviceinstaller
Error: No such keg: /usr/local/Cellar/ideviceinstaller
Michaels-MacBook-Air:~ michael.nares$ brew install --HEAD ideviceinstaller
==> Cloning 
Updating 
==> ./autogen.sh
installed software in a non-standard prefix.

Alternatively, you may set the environment variables libimobiledevice_CFLAGS
and libimobiledevice_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
See the pkg-config man page for more details.
Error: Homebrew doesn't know what compiler versions ship with your version
of Xcode (6.1.1). Please `brew update` and if that doesn't help, file
an issue with the output of `brew --config`:

Note that we only track stable, released versions of Xcode.

Thanks!


Michaels-MacBook-Air:~ michael.nares$
```

However when I go to “Finder” and do <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> I can’t find it. Is there any way of knowing where it’s been installed to?

Comment: There are links missing from the output because I don't have enough reputation to post links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However when I go to “Finder” and do <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> I
>   can’t find it. Is there any way of knowing where it’s been installed
>   to?

There are a few ways you can approach this.

#### Check the Homebrew formula itself.

First, let’s look at the Homebrew formula for `ideviceinstaller` itself [as seen in the official Homebrew GitHub repository](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/Library/Formula/ideviceinstaller.rb). You don’t have to be a deep programmer or understand tons of Ruby—which Homebrew is built on—to interpret this code. The key section is the `test do` area near the bottom:

```
test do
  system "#{bin}/ideviceinstaller --help |grep -q ^Usage"
end
```

Note the `#{bin}` that precedes the `ideviceinstaller` binary call. That `#{bin}` variable translates to `/usr/local/bin` so we know that the full path of the `ideviceinstaller` binary should be `/usr/local/bin/ideviceinstaller`.

#### Check using `which`.

To confirm the full path to `ideviceinstaller`, you can just use `which` from the command line in the Terminal like so:

```
which ideviceinstaller
```

And the returned path should be the same `/usr/local/bin/ideviceinstaller` as deduced from the Homebrew formula above.

#### Check using `brew info`.

That said, the output you presented shows this path:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/ideviceinstaller
```

And you can confirm this via Homebrew itself like this:

```
brew info ideviceinstaller
```

Now why would it be in `/usr/local/Cellar/` as well as `/usr/local/bin/`? Easy. That `/usr/local/Cellar/` is where Homebrew would install the files, but symbolic links would be made to `/usr/local/bin/` to allow for easy, systemwide access of the binaries. At least that is what I am assuming based on my knowledge of how Mac OS X works and how Linux works and how many developers deal with installing binaries like this from source code.

#### Checking via `locate` in the Terminal.

If all else fails, you can also use the Terminal version of “Spotlight” known as `locate` from the Terminal. You would simply run a command like this:

```
locate ideviceinstaller
```

And that command should return a list of file paths with the word `ideviceinstaller` in them. If you don’t get any results you might just need to update the `locate` database like this:

```
sudo /usr/libexec/locate.updatedb
```

And then run the command again.